# How to ask for string and then use it as a part of an array?

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I have an complex problem,I have  arrays which holds informations about championship league  informations like

```
var teamstats=[ Bayern Munich: {wins:4,loses:1,goals:9,draws:2},
              Fc Barcelona: {wins:4,loses:1,goals:9,draws:2},
               ..... ]
```

I can reach every team stats with writing on console like
 `teamstats.Bayern Munich`
My problem is: I have to ask team name from the user  and then print the stats of the team.
edit:
Getting string part is OK. And I have tried

```
var str = {"teamfromuser"}
var x=eval(str)
```

Comment: You can use prompt command to ask user to input information

Comment: Hmm some IE will not accept *prompt* (unless security options are changed...)

Comment: You've not written valid _JavaScript_, this looks like it should be an _Object_. You can get all keys on an _Object_ as an _Array_ via `Object.keys` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use the following HTML:

```
<select id="teams"></select> <button id="show_stats">Show Stats</button>
<div id="stats"></div>
```

You can populate the `select` with the teams from your `teamstats` and then use this as the user input to display the stats, something similar to the following:

```
var teamstats = {
        "Bayern Munich": {wins:4,loses:1,goals:9,draws:2},
        "Fc Barcelona": {wins:1,loses:4,goals:3,draws:2}
    },
    teams = document.getElementById('teams');

for (var team in teamstats) {
    teams.appendChild(new Option(team, team));
}

document.getElementById('show_stats').onclick = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var stats = document.getElementById('stats'),
        teamstat = teamstats[teams.options[teams.selectedIndex].value];

    stats.innerHTML = '';
    for (var stat in teamstat) {
        stats.innerHTML += stat + ': ' + teamstat[stat] + '<br>';
    }
};
```

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wY2XP/)

Note: This is not completely best-practice Javascript as far as event handling and cross-browser compatibility, it is just a proof of concept to get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

In the way you've provided it your team stats are not valid JavaScript nor even JSON
They should be written as

```
var teamstats={ "Bayern Munich": {wins:4,loses:1,goals:9,draws:2},
              "Fc Barcelona": {wins:4,loses:1,goals:9,draws:2},
               ..... };
```

And so to look up for particular item you will use

```
var key = "Bayern Munich";
var stats = teamstats[key];
```